# PhpStorm - Debugger not listening with proxy

Tags: php, apache, cookies, proxy, phpstorm

I'm using Mac OSX.

I have a docker machine on IP `192.168.99.100` which listening to port `8080` and forward to traffic to my `Ubuntu` container.

The Ubuntu container has Apache and PHP installed in it.

When i'm adding a break point to my php file, a cookie with debug session to my request and set the listening to debug session in my PhpStorm to work - browsing to `192.168.99.100:8080/my/path/to/php/file` trigger a breakpoint.

I add a forwarding in my apache vhost config file so I could browse to:

```
localhost:8080/my/path/to/php/file
```

browsing works perfectly, but the debugging is not being triggered.

Running:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

shows that the cookie was forward during the apache proxy process.

**This is my apache config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ProxyPass               /       http://192.168.99.100:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse        /       http://192.168.99.100:8080/
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  /       http://192.168.99.100:8080/
</VirtualHost>

Listen 8080
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can use XDebug through a reverse proxy... :(

Comment: *"browsing works perfectly, but the debugging is not being triggered."* How do you know that for sure? What xdebug log has to say about it? I'm sorry for possibly rude question .. but do you know how actually xdebug works?